# Chaining promises with promises inside then()

Tags: javascript, promise

How do you chain in an scenario like this?

*api* is a function that returns a promise after an http request. *auth* is a function that returns a promise after *api* respond, if resolves *api* is called for a second time, if not *auth* rejects.

I tried this, but not only am I going back to the callback hell, it does not work.

```
function api(query) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     //DO SOME STUFF AND SOMETIMES resolves...
   })
}

function auth() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     api("/foo").then(function(asset1) {
        api("/bar").then(function(asset2) {
           resolve(asset2);
        }).catch(function() {
           reject();
        })
     }).catch(function(error) {
        reject();
     })

   })
}
```

Comment: Can `/foo` and `/bar` be called concurrently or does `/bar` rely on the result of `/foo`? It appears that `asset1` is never used.`

Answer (score 13):

A cleaner way to do it:

```
return myFirstPromise.then( (returnFromFirst) => {
    //Do something
    return secondPromise();
}).then( (returnFromSecond) => {
    //Do something
    return thirdPromise();
}).then( (returnFromThird) => {
    //All Done
}).catch( (e) =>{}
    console.error("SOMETHING WENT WRONG!!!");
);
```

Answer (score 9):

As far as i understand what you are trying to do, following code will also resolve with `asset2`. Besides that i guess `api` function is doing http request so you could benefit from using `request-promise` lib instead of converting callback api with `new Promise` thing.

```
function api(query) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     //DO SOME STUFF AND SOMETIMES resolves...
   })
}

function auth() {
   return api("/foo")
   .then(() => api("/bar"))
}
```

With this caller would do something like:

```
auth()
.then(asset2 => ...)
.catch(err => ...)
```

If order of calling `api` is not important, like @styfle pointed out in comment, you could write it using `Promise.all`

```
function auth () {
  return Promise.all([
    api("/foo"),
    api("/bar")
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this should help you.

Just an observation: `then` method always return a promise based on the previous promise resolution. If the previous promise is resolved it will pass the resolved value to the next promise. Otherwise it will send the error to the `catch` method.

```
function auth () {
  /*
    Since `then` already returns a new Promise, 
    you don't need to create a new Promise.
  */
  return api('/foo').then(function (asset1) {
    return api('/bar')
  })
}

/*
  So you can call auth:
*/

auth().then(function (asset2) {
  console.log('This is my asset2:', asset2)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error('Error', error)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

from [Promises standard](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-49):

> If x is a promise, adopt its state [3.4]:
> If x is pending, promise must remain pending until x is fulfilled or rejected.
> If/when x is fulfilled, fulfill promise with the same value.
> If/when x is rejected, reject promise with the same reason.

The next example prints 'finalVal':

```
let resolveP1 = null;

let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolveP1 = resolve;
});

let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(p1);
});

let p3 = p2.then(function(finalVal) {
    console.log(finalVal);
});

resolveP1('finalVal')
```